# Cordova 7 how to show white status bar with with black icons and text?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to show white status bar with black icons and text. I am able to set the status bar color to white but icons and text are still in white color. How can I change color of icons and text also I need same styles for iOS

Thanks,

MSK

Answer (score 2):

Install `cordova-plugin-statusbar` if you have not done it yet

And call `StatusBar.styleDefault();` after device ready event fires.

Or add it as a preference in the config.xml

```
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
```